# Is there any way to map on arrays, and return an array in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm going to operate an array, do some calculation for each row of data, and return an array.
for example:

```
a = [[1,4], [2,5], [3, 6]]
def op(x):
    return x[0] - x[1], x[0]+x[1]
c = map(op, a) #[(-3, 5), (-3, 7), (-3, 9)]
d, e = zip(*c)
print d, e
```

but I found c is an array of tuples. So I had to unzip c.
Is there a way for map to return an array? Many thanks.
I know I can convert c to an array by numpy.asarray. any better idea?

Comment: Array is a numpy type. Your `a` is a list of lists. Is that what you would like to have as the result value of `map`? `thefourtheye`shows below how to do that. However, if have large lists, try to use Numpy arrays, they are very simple and efficient for this kind of calculations.

Comment: @DrV Thank you. I mixed up the concept. I'll use numpy array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
return a, b
```

Python will build a tuple and return it. So, we need to explicitly create a list and return it like this

```
def op(x):
    return [x[0] - x[1], x[0] + x[1]]
```